# SMS sending through Alarmmanager

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, android-broadcast, android-alarms

My code given below shows me that it works fine whenever i debug. In **Mainactivity** class, when i press the button on the Map. The pending intent calls the broadcast receiver and passes the Longitude and latitude. I checked it in debug. The values are properly passed and smsmanager is also being called. However, when i asked the debugger to just send the sms its stuck (Just keep pressing the F8 button and not moving forward) and no sms is sent to specified number. In addition to this i m also using alarmmanager but i think there is some problem which i couldnt figured out.

> **MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    super.onResume();
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

}

OnClickListener btnShareLocationOnClick = new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(mapView.getGpsLocation()!= null){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(this_, SendSmsReceiver.class);
                  intent.setAction("com.android.myapp.ACTION");
                  intent.putExtra("longitude", mapView.getGpsLocation().getLongitude());
                  intent.putExtra("latitude", mapView.getGpsLocation().getLatitude());
                  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                               .getBroadcast(this_, 0, intent,
                                             PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

                  alarm.cancel(pendingIntent);
                  alarm.setRepeating(
                            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            System.currentTimeMillis()+1000, 
                            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, 
                            pendingIntent);
            }
            d.dismiss();
        }
    };
```

**d.dismiss** just dismiss the dialog box from which i press the button

**SendSmsReceiver**

```
public class SendSmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String phoneNumberReciver="XXXX"; 
    double lonPresent = intent.getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0.0);
    double latPresent = intent.getDoubleExtra("latitude",0.0);
    String message="AndroidCoordinates\n"+lonPresent+" Break "+ latPresent;
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault(); 
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumberReciver, "5554", message, null, null);
}
```

}

**XXXX** may be any phone number

**Manifast**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<receiver android:name="com.myapp.smssending.SendSmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.myapp.ACTION" />
        </intent-filter>
       </receiver>
```

Comment: Well, for sure you shouldn't be calling `super.onResume()` in your `onCreate()`. That's definitely a no-no.

Comment: Are you debugging in an emulator or on a device? What Android version are you using?

Comment: I m using android version 4.2.2 for debugging

Comment: @DavidWasser you r absoubtly right. I have change the code. Thanks but my problem is not resolved

Comment: Are you on an actual device, or on an emulator?

Comment: @DavidWasser i m on emulator

Comment: You should try this on a real device. I have no idea if any of the SMS stuff works on the emulator.

Comment: Thanks @DavidWasser this really worked but it is strange that emulator was showing stranger behavior.

Comment: Not really. SMS is telephony and the emulator doesn't really simulate telephony. In my experience it is faster, easier and more accurate to test on real devices. Glad you got your problem solved.

Comment: @DavidWasser Again i m thankful to u for guidance

Comment: @DavidWasser you said that SMS is telephony and emulator doesn't simulate telephony. Then how it can be possible that we can send sms to Emulator from DDMS and that msg is show received in inbox as well as we have notification?

Comment: Yes, it does simulate some telephony, but I've found that it is easier and more reliable to test telephony stuff on a real device. It looks like you can send an SMS from one emulator instance to another, but obviously not from an emulator to a real device.